# JQMIGRATE: Global events are undocumented and deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-migrate

We're trying to upgrade our jquery using jquery migrate.

We get the "JQMIGRATE: Global events are undocumented and deprecated" on this code (a wrapper for jquery.ajax):

```
ajaxPost: function (url, jsonData, successCallback, async) {
        if (async == null) {
            async = true;
        }

        var ajaxSettings = {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            async: async,
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            success: function (data, code, xht) {
                successCallback(data, code, xht);
            },
            error: function (xht, errorType, exception) {
               console.log(...);
            }
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxSettings);
}
```

The "error" occurs for this line:

```
 successCallback(data, code, xht);
```

We're not sure how to fix it?!

Comment: Can you provide ommited code? By what you have given, try   jQuery.ajaxSetup({global: false})

Comment: we tried it, did not change anything, we got the message anyway.., provided the complete code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a piece of code from JQMIGRATE responsible for warning

```
// Turn global events into document-triggered events
jQuery.event.trigger = function( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers  ){
    if ( !elem && !rajaxEvent.test( event ) ) {
        migrateWarn( "Global events are undocumented and deprecated" );
    }
    return eventTrigger.call( this,  event, data, elem || document, onlyHandlers  );
};
```

Looks like this warning is popping on trigger() calls in two cases:

1) no element is specified as trigger context

2) event is global ajax event

Global ajax event example:

```
  $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $("#loading").show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $("#loading").hide();
 });
```

But if you say you had disabled global events by setting jQuery.ajaxSetup({global: false}), then
problem could be caused by case 1, but i dont see any code releavant to it in the provided fragment.

Probably you need to check implementation of method ***successCallback*** for case 1.

Comment: You were right, we had a implementation in a callback like " $.event.trigger", that was it, thanks a lot!